# How to make an extended http request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I wanted log in a website, and then, send a post request through the logged account. I had tried using a request inside another request, but for obvious reasons that didn't work.

Comment: Sounds like what you really need to do is handle cookies.

Comment: This could work. But for now, I need to fix the first POST request then i'll try handle cookies. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into the first of many features/problems that might make using nodejs/javascript a little bit confusing in the beginning. You have to move your second call into the closure of the first one, otherwise, the second one will be handled (asynchronously) parallel to the first one instead of waiting for the first one.

```
var request = require('request')                                 
const cookieJar = request.jar()

request({
    jar: cookieJar, 
    method: "POST",
    baseUrl: "https://www.sitehere.com",
    uri: "/login",
    form: { 
      username: "username",
      password: "password",
      autologin: "true"}
    },function(err,httpResponse,body){ 
     console.log(body); 
     request({
      jar: cookieJar, 
      method: "POST",
      baseUrl: "https://www.sitehere.com",
      uri: "/postmessage",
      form: { 
      message: "test"
      }
    }, function(err,httpResponse,body){ console.log(body); })
})
```

To make your life a lot easier, I'd recommend you first have a look at how nodejs handles asynchronicity, what that means in connection with closures and how to avoid callback hell using promises through the more up-to-date async/await syntax.

**Update:** As @Brad noted in the comments, you might also want to persist the cookies from the request which is why I added a cookie jar.

Comment: You could also use a `.then(){...}` to verify if the login was successful and then send the second request.

Comment: I still get body empty. I suppose that it happens because the page redirect to another one. What should I do ? Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, but that makes the answer not wrong, just incomplete. I'll add a comment to it. The ajax example suggests that cookies are being used, but other forms of logging in could also be feasible, which is why I didn't further specify what to do after the first request goes through.